# how to initialize a static constexpr member of std::vector<std::string> in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, initialization, constexpr

I'm trying to initialize a `static constexpr std::vector` of `std::string`s inside my class `Foo`. I will later use the address of its elements.

```
class Foo {
public:
  static constexpr std::vector<std::string> a = {"a", "bc", "232"}; // not working, constexpr variable not literal ....
  const std::vector<std::string> a = {"a", "bc", "232"}; // this works
}
```

using c++11, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can. If you add details of how you wish to use the variable, you might get some useful feedback. For a variable to be `constexpr`, it must meet the requirements of a [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). A `std::vector<std::string>` does not qualify as a LiteralType.

Comment: No `constexpr` constructors for `std::vector` (or for `std::string`) so I don't see a way to initialize a `constexpr std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: I can live with const instead of constexpr. but it's a little bit odd that there's no way to do this.

Comment: @TMS why is this surprising to you? `vector` and `string` contain data that is dynamically allocated at runtime only. They can't be allocated at compile time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, oh, maybe replace vector with std::array here. but you're right, vector is not a good example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can live with const instead of constexpr. but it's a little bit odd that there's no way to do this

It's good you can live with `const` but, just for fun, I show you a way to make a better-than-nothing `constexpr` `static` member that uses `std::array` instead of `std::vector` and (again) `std::array` instead of `std::string`.

Unfortunately you're using C++11, so no `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` (available starting from C++14) but I add a C++11 substitute in the following full example.

If you know a superior limit for the length of the strings you want use in the `constexpr` member, say 9 (3 in you example), you can define a `fakeString` type as follows

```
using fakeString = std::array<char, 10u>;
```

Observe that the size of the `std::array` is max-length plus one (plus the final zero).

Now you can define `foo` as follows

```
struct foo
 {
   static constexpr std::array<fakeString, 3u> a
    {{ fs("a"), fs("bc"), fs("232") }};
 };

constexpr std::array<fakeString, 3u> foo::a;
```

where `fs()` is a `constexpr` function that return a `fakeString` given a C-style array of `char` and uses a `fsh()` helper functions

The `fs()` and `fsh()` functions are as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t N>
constexpr fakeString fsh (indexSequence<Is...> const &, char const (&s)[N])
 { return {{ s[Is]... }}; }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr fakeString fs (char const (&s)[N])
 { return fsh(makeIndexSequence<N>{}, s); }
```

Now you can use `foo::a` as follows

```
   for ( auto const & fakeS : foo::a )
      std::cout << fakeS.data() << std::endl;
```

Observe that you have to call the `data()` method that return a `char *`, that is a C-style string.

I repeat: just for fun.

The following is a full compiling C++11 example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t...>
struct indexSequence
 { using type = indexSequence; };

template <typename, typename>
struct concatSequences;

template <std::size_t... S1, std::size_t... S2>
struct concatSequences<indexSequence<S1...>, indexSequence<S2...>>
   : public indexSequence<S1..., ( sizeof...(S1) + S2 )...>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
struct makeIndexSequenceH
   : public concatSequences<
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<(N>>1)>::type,
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<N-(N>>1)>::type>::type
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<0> : public indexSequence<>
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<1> : public indexSequence<0>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename makeIndexSequenceH<N>::type;

using fakeString = std::array<char, 10u>;

template <std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t N>
constexpr fakeString fsh (indexSequence<Is...> const &, char const (&s)[N])
 { return {{ s[Is]... }}; }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr fakeString fs (char const (&s)[N])
 { return fsh(makeIndexSequence<N>{}, s); }

struct foo
 {
   static constexpr std::array<fakeString, 3u> a
    {{ fs("a"), fs("bc"), fs("232") }};
 };

constexpr std::array<fakeString, 3u> foo::a;

int main ()
 {
   for ( auto const & fakeS : foo::a )
      std::cout << fakeS.data() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that std::array is actually what I want. and giving me the examples.